# In Spain, can I land and take off from my own property?

Tags: regulations, spain

I have a property in Spain with a big field; is it legal to take off from and land on your own property in a light aircraft?

Comment: I edited your question to fix spelling and add a couple relevant tags.  Welcome to Aviation Stack Exchange!  If you haven't done so, please read through the [FAQ] and take the [tour] to learn more about how Stack Exchange works.

Comment: There's going to be no "general" case ... imagine your land is under the end of the main runway at "pick your favourite airport".  And then there will be exclusion zones, etc.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your local and national regulations.  In some jurisdictions, local municipalities can regulate use of land in that way, and in others they can't.  So first check with Spanish national regulations (if separate from EASA) on what constitutes an aerodrome or airport to see if there are any restrictions on use of an unlicensed piece of land as an aerodrome (probably not), then check with local municipal regulations or zoning or use bylaws that may restrict use of your land as an aerodrome (a definite possibility).

Answer (score -1):

No, unless you present a project of the airfield and get it approved by the municipal and aviation authorities. Not impossible, but very slow. Think in two or three years of negotiations before you can even start construction...

Comment: Could you cite the rule that makes this the case?

Comment: No, and not only because it's not just one rule. Besides, Spain is a very diverse and de-centralized country, so that different places have different rules.

Comment: If Spain is so diverse and decentralized, how are you sure that this is the true answer for all of Spain?